# An error occurred during rendering of the report in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have created the SSRS Report and created New Subscription for it.

I am Saving the report in Shared Location through Subscription. Report is Generating properly in shared location when i am using CSV and EXCEL 2003 format for output. But I am getting below error when i am tiring to save the file in EXCE and EXCEL(No Header) Format.

> "Failure writing file [Report Name] : An error occurred during
>   rendering of the report"

Note: Both the formats are working properly when I am saving file from online I am getting error only in Subscriptions.

Please provide solution for the same

Find the details from Log files below

> e ERROR: Throwing
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UnhandledReportRenderingException:
>   ,
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UnhandledReportRenderingException:
>   An error occurred during rendering of the report. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.ReportRenderingException:
>   An error occurred during rendering of the report. --->
>   System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException: Unable to
>   determine the identity of domain.    at
>   System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorage._GetAccountingInfo(Evidence
>   evidence, Type evidenceType, IsolatedStorageScope fAssmDomApp, Object&
>   oNormalized)    at
>   System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorage.GetAccountingInfo(Evidence
>   evidence, Type evidenceType, IsolatedStorageScope fAssmDomApp, String&
>   typeName, String& instanceName)    at
>   System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorage._InitStore(IsolatedStorageScope
>   scope, Evidence domainEv, Type domainEvidenceType, Evidence assemEv,
>   Type assemblyEvidenceType, Evidence appEv, Type appEvidenceType)    at
>   System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorage.InitStore(IsolatedStorageScope
>   scope, Type domainEvidenceType, Type assemblyEvidenceType)    at
>   System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope
>   scope, Type domainEvidenceType, Type assemblyEvidenceType)    at
>   MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.ReliableIsolatedStorageFileFolder..ctor()
>   at
>   MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.GetDefaultIsolatedStorageFile()
>   at
>   MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.PackagingUtilities.CreateUserScopedIsolatedStorageFileStreamWithRandomName(Int32
>   retryCount, String& fileName)    at
>   MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.EnsureIsolatedStoreStream()
>   at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.SparseMemoryStream.SwitchModeIfNecessary()
>   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOFileItemStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count)    at
>   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.InternalWrite(Byte[] array, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count, Boolean isAsync)    at
>   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 count)    at
>   MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count)    at
>   MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ProgressiveCrcCalculatingStream.Write(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
>   MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOModeEnforcingStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer.XMLModel.XMLStreamsheetModel.WriteStreamToStream(Stream
>   from, Stream to)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer.XMLModel.XMLStreamsheetModel.Cleanup()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer.OpenXmlGenerator.FinalizeWorksheet()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer.OpenXmlGenerator.SaveSpreadsheet(Stream
>   outputStream, Stream backgroundImage, UInt16 backgroundImageWidth,
>   UInt16 backgroundImageHeight)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelRenderer.ExcelRenderer.Render(Report
>   report, NameValueCollection reportServerParameters,
>   NameValueCollection deviceInfo, NameValueCollection
>   clientCapabilities, Hashtable& renderProperties,
>   CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStream)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelRenderer.ExcelRenderer.Render(Report
>   report, NameValueCollection reportServerParameters,
>   NameValueCollection deviceInfo, NameValueCollection
>   clientCapabilities, Hashtable& renderProperties,
>   CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStream)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.Execution.RenderReport.InvokeRenderer(IRenderingExtension
>   renderer, Report report, NameValueCollection reportServerParameters,
>   NameValueCollection deviceInfo, NameValueCollection
>   clientCapabilities, Hashtable& renderProperties,
>   CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStream)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.Execution.RenderReport.Execute(IRenderingExtension
>   newRenderer)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you may have run into [this known issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/764356/subscription-fails-due-to-error-system-io-isolatedstorage-isolatedstorageexception-unable-to-determine-the-identity-of-domain) with SSRS.

Try staggering your subscriptions as suggested in the Connect article, or if your resulting report is > 10 MB maybe see if the amount of data in the report can be reduced or a different output format is acceptable.